# Call another class' constructors in member function

Tags: visual-c++

I created a pointer array in class 'box' and called a function put_in_box to new a 'things' class obj and point the index pointer to it. When run the local debugger, prompted the Error C2514 'things':class has no constructors. if I remove the line "index[j] = new things(j);" in box class definition, I will be able to get a expected result by using "blue_box.index[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKO3U.png) = new things(2);" in main function.

My question is: the things class do have a constructor, why I cannot call it from another class' member function?  Is there a way to do the same job?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class box;
class things;

class box {
public:
    things *index[50];[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    void put_in_things(int j) {
        index[j] = new things(j);
    }

};



class things {
public:
    int i;
    things(int i_) :i(i_) { cout << "things constructed" << endl; }
    things(things&c) {
        i = c.i;
    }
    ~things(){}
};


int main() {

    box blue_box;
    blue_box.put_in_things(1);

    blue_box.index[1] = new things(2);

    return 0;
```

Comment: C++ uses a single-pass compile model.  At the put_in_things() method it does not yet know anything about the things class.  You have to move the method definition beyond the things class declaration.

Comment: thank you so much, problem solved.